# Swap words spans

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few spans like this:

```
<span class="test">word1 word2 @ different content test </span>
<span class="test">word3 word4 @ different content test343wer</span>
<span class="test">example54 example98 @ different content3453</span>
<span class="test">word13 word92 @ different content1111111</span>
<span class="test">word223 word14 @ different content00</span>
```

And i need this output:

```
<span class="test">word2 word1</span>
<span class="test">word4 word3</span>
<span class="test">example98 example54</span>
<span class="test">word92 word13</span>
<span class="test">word14 word223</span>
```

Notice that the first two words have swapped position and everything from @ is stripped.

I have tested with this code but its incomplete and not working. And it uses an ID not a CLASS:

```
var datetime = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
var date = datetime.substr(0, datetime.indexOf('@')).trim();      
var reverse = date.split(" ");
reverse.reverse();
var result = (reverse[0] + ' ' + reverse[1])
console.log(result);
```

The number of spans may vary

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to `split()` the text by the spaces, get the first two elements of the resulting array, reverse them, then join them back together in a string, something like this:

```js
$('.test').text(function(i, t) {
  return t.trim().split(' ').slice(0, 2).reverse().join(' ');
})
```

```css
span { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">word1 word2 @ different content</span>
<span class="test">word3 word4 @ different content</span>
<span class="test">example54 example98 @ different content</span>
<span class="test">word13 word92 @ different content</span>
<span class="test">word223 word14 @ different content</span>
```

Comment: Thats nice one@Rory McCrossan accept this @user6079228, working perfectly with minimal code

Answer (score 2):

Need to use `$.each()` with bit improvement in number of code-lines:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.test').each(function(){
    var spantext = $(this).html().split(" ").slice(0,2).reverse();
    $(this).html(spantext[0] + ' ' + spantext[1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">word1 word2 @ different content</span>
<span class="test">word3 word4 @ different content</span>
<span class="test">example54 example98 @ different content</span>
<span class="test">word13 word92 @ different content</span>
<span class="test">word223 word14 @ different content</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, works good. But the other answer has less code so i accepted that one.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Btw love Rory's answer above for its brevity.**

well, in jquery you could do it like this:

```
$(".test").each(
    function(index) {
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = text.split('@')[0].split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
    $(this).html(text);
  }
);
```

JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/q2xc1c0b/3/